# dylib : library not loaded : Reason : image not found in swift 5

Tags: xcode, macos, dylib, swift5

I want to use .dylib file into my project , .dylib file is created from go lang. same .dylib file in working fine in macOS command line project but giving error in macOS application project

Steps followed for including file
 
1)Created a macOS Application project
 
2) Pasted .dylib file in project root directory
3) After pasting file inside root directory of project ,I have
added .dylib file to the project by using File >> Add file "project"
 
4) changed library settings from  “Don’t Embed” to “Embed without signing” .

Also tried to drag and drop .dylib file

Error

```
dyld: Library not loaded:
Reason: image not found
```

I was getting same error when I was trying to use same .dylib file with macOS command line application but after changing library setting from “Do not Embed to Embed without signing ”  error got resolved.

Comment: Can you post the output of `otool -D [YOUR_DYLIB]` please?

Comment: There will be some `install_name_tool` jiggery pokery required, I'm sure.  Checkout [a python script](https://github.com/trojanfoe/xcodedevtools/blob/master/copy_dylibs.py) I wrote for this purpose.